# Unable to manualy compile kernel 6.1.2 kali

Tags: linux, kali-linux, kernel

I'm trying to manually compile the linux 6.1.2 from source code to get the latest kernel revision. I actually have Kali 2022.4 whit the 6.0 Kernel. I'm using this [website](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/build-linux-kernel) step
I just did a fresh kali install, installed nothing except the update with `apt-get upgrade` command, then tried to compile again. Same error:

```
  INSTALL /boot
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 6.1.2 /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.2
dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.1.2:Sign command: /lib/modules/6.1.2/build/scripts/sign-file
Binary /lib/modules/6.1.2/build/scripts/sign-file not found, modules won't be signed
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 6.1.2 cannot be found at /lib/modules/6.1.2/build or /lib/modules/6.1.2/source.
Please install the linux-headers-6.1.2 package or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located.
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 failed!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
make: *** [arch/x86/Makefile:286: install] Error 1
```

Since I'm actually using the 6.0 Kernel, the only available kernel headers in repository is for the 6.0 kernel, not the 6.1.2. The headers for the 6.0 kernel is already installed.

Thank for your help

Comment: I have not needed to upgrade my Kali kernel at this point. Version upgrades do that. Try the Kali documentation adapted for Kernel Version 6 and see if that works. https://www.kali.org/docs/development/recompiling-the-kali-linux-kernel/

Comment: When using those step: this is the error:
tmp/ccezbTas.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccezbTas.s:118715: Error: bad expression
/tmp/ccezbTas.s:118715: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character valued 0x11
/tmp/ccezbTas.s:118715: Error: no such instruction: `us1631'

Comment: I am not sure then. I looked around for other steps and did not find any. Sorry,

Comment: "*then tried to compile again*" -- What do you mean by "*again*"? How many times have you done this kernel build?  "*the only available kernel headers in repository is for the 6.0 kernel, not the 6.1.2.*" -- Which steps in that guide have you actually performed? If you actually downloaded and extracted the kernel source code, then you would already have the necessary "*kernel headers*" (i.e. they are in the kernel source).